# Table column names to array in ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

In Rails I would simply use:

```
MyModel.column_names
```

to access the tables column names, but I am enduring my first fumblings with Sinatra (in order to better learn Ruby) and need to get the column names of a table into an array.

Previously, I have iterated over the params hash to extract key, value pairs:

```
params.each do |key, value|
  #manipulate keys and values
end
```

and know that using:

```
@mm = MyModel.new
@mm.each do ....
```

leads to an undefined method 'each' error.

```
logger.info @mm.inspect
```

logs something like:

```
#<MyModel @id=nil @start=nil @end=nil @yada=nil @created_at=nil @updated_at=nil @foreign_id=nil>
```

So, how do I get those blasted column names I can see so clearly into an array?

Thanks...

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Doon for pointing me in the right direction with Datamapper properties.

I ended up making a private method column_names:

```
def self.column_names
  self.properties.collect {|column| column.name.to_s }
end
```

which works a treat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `properties` ?

http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Model/Property

Comment: Thanks Doon -- just the ticket

Answer (score 0):

For any Ruby object you have the methods `instance_variables` that returns the array of that object’s attributes.  Is that too generic for you?  I’m not familiar with DataMapper, there may be a specific method to do the equivalent of `column_names` in ActiveRecord.